# Problem in Understanding the Proof of a Well-Known Theorem in Limits of Functions.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, functions, proof-explanation

Let $g : D\to \Bbb R$ be a function on $D$ and $(c,\infty)\subseteq D$ for
some $c\in\Bbb R.$ Then,  $\lim_{x\to\infty} g(x) = l$ ( $l\in\Bbb R$ ) iff $\lim_{x\to 0+}g(\frac 1x)= l.$

The proof of this popular theorem, is given as follows:

Let $f(x) = 1/x.$ Then $\lim_{x\to 0+} f(x) =\infty.$

> Let $\lim_{x\to\infty}g(x) = l.$ Then for a pre-assigned positive $\epsilon$ there exists a positive number $d > c$ such that $| g(x) -l |< \epsilon $ for all $x > d. $ Since $\lim_{x\to 0+} f(x) =\infty,$ for the chosen positive number $d,$ there exists $\delta >0$ such that $f(x) > d$ for all $x\in (0,\delta).$
>
> Therefore $|g\circ f(x) - l|< \epsilon$ for all $x\in (0,\delta).$
>
> This implies that $\lim_{x\to 0+}  g\circ f(x) = l,$ i.e., $\lim_{x\to 0+}g\circ f(x)= \lim_{x\to 0+} g(\frac 1x)=l. $
>
> Conversely, let $\lim_{x\to 0+}g(\frac 1x)= l.$ Then for a pre-assigned positive $\epsilon$ there exists a positive $\delta$ such that
> $l - \epsilon < g\circ f(x) < l + \epsilon,$ for all $x\in (0,\delta)\cap D;$  $D$ being the domain of $g\circ f.$ Again,
> $x\in (0,\delta)\implies f(x)\gt\frac 1 {\delta}.$ Hence $l - \epsilon < g(x) < l + \epsilon$ for all $x > \frac{1}{\delta}.$
>
> This implies that $\lim_{x\to\infty} g(x) = l.$
>
> This completes the proof.

---

Now, there are a couple of things, which I didn't get. I will enlist my doubts on this particular proof as follows:

- I did not get, how they write,

> This implies that $\lim_{x\to 0+} g\circ f(x) = l,$ i.e., $\lim_{x\to 0+}g\circ f(x)= \lim_{x\to 0+} g(\frac 1x)=l. $

From what followed previously, till then, they had proven the assertion, that:

*"$\forall \epsilon\gt 0$ there exists a $\delta\gt 0$ such that if, $x\in (0,\delta)$ we have, $|g\circ f(x)-l|=|g(1/x)-l|\lt \epsilon.$"*

But from this, I don't understand how they wrote, $\lim_{x\to 0+} g\circ f(x) = l.$ This is because, the notation, $g\circ f(x)$ cannot be used, just like that. It can be used, only if, we have, $f(\Bbb R^*)\subseteq D.$ Otherwise, using the notation, $g\circ f(x)$ would be highly erroneous.

- It seems that while proving the converse part as well, they are using the assumption, that the domain of $f$ is equal to $D$. This is because, there they write,

> Conversely, let $\lim_{x\to 0+}g(\frac 1x)= l.$ Then for a pre-assigned positive $\epsilon$ there exists a positive $\delta$ such that
> $l - \epsilon < \color{red}{g\circ f(x)} < l + \epsilon,$ for all $x\in (0,\delta)\cap D;$  **$D$ being the domain of $g\circ f.$**

Now, from where did the $\delta$ pop up out of nowhere in the rest part? This seems weird.

Any help regarding this two issues will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Didn’t you ask this already?

Comment: @FShrike I know what you're talking about. But they are not the same. That was my approach. This was the book's approach. But I  need to understand this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see why you might be frustrated but there are no real issues here. It is implicit in the definition of limit that we don’t really care about the domain of the function; we only need to quantify over some local neighbourhood of the point.

At the very beginning you wrote “let $f(x)=1/x$”. However if you want to be über-rigorous about domains and composition *later* you should start as you mean to go on! Take some positive $c>0$ such that $(c,\infty)\subseteq D$. Now we give a proper definition for $f$; put $f:(0,c^{-1})\to D$ via $x\mapsto1/x$. This is a well-defined function and the composite $g\circ f$ is also well-defined; you can have no quarrel with this since the codomain of $f$ exactly matches the domain of $g$.

Although technically wrong, the usage in the post is not exactly ‘highly erroneous’. It is very common to make minor abuses of notation and lapses in rigour when it is understood that both reader and author could make it precise, if pressed. There are various issues and benefits associated with this; a whole can of worms.

The second issue, where they suppose the domain of $f$ is $D$, is an honest mistake. I’d wager that they meant to *denote by* $D$ the domain of $f$ and they intended to leave it to the reader to find a sensible, precise *choice* of definition of $D$, but they forgot that $D$ was previously used to denote the domain of $g$.

Finally, $\delta$ “popped up” from the very definition of limit! Such $\delta$ always exists precisely because $g(1/x)$ was supposed to tend to $\ell$ as $x\to0^+$.

Comment: Thanks ton! That makes a lot of sense now. But how toproof the converse part then?

Comment: @ThomasFinley The proof of the converse is already fine! Just remove all reference to “$D$” and it works

Comment: Should I remove it by replacing $D$ by say a $D'$ ? IS $D'=(0,c^{-1})$?

Comment: @ThomasFinley you can *choose* $D’=(0,c^{-1})$, yes. Many many different choices will suffice.

Comment: Thanks a ton! I do get it now.